# iPhone: I call protocol_conformsToProtocol function and it shows implicit declaration warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I got 2 Protocol* object and want to check if they conform each other.

I use

> BOOL protocol_conformsToProtocol(Protocol *proto, Protocol *other)

but it shows a warning

> Implicit declaration of function 'protocol_conformsToProtocol'

What do I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you including the right headers? I think [`protocol_conformsToProtocol`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-SW63) is declared in `<objc/runtime.h>`.

```
#include <objc/runtime.h>
```